# How to manage session with ember framework?

Tags: rest, ember.js, jax-rs

I have been asked to use ember for front end and java rest services as the backend. I am trying to figure out how to manage session for a particular user. 
i know there are couple of options like storing in the local store, cookie but they are error prone as some users might disable those features. I want to know what is the preferred approach in normal enterprise apps. 
Mine app is simple 15 page app. i need to capture user, and some profile details.

Answer (score 0):

Session are usually more of server side part. You have to just make sure whether the provided session is available or not for every transformed route and request. There is a library which takes care of authentication and authorization in ember https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth.